# pandas construct multi index for columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I construct a multi-index in pandas for an example dataframe of:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'value_mean':[1,5], 'value_max':[40,100]})
```

Transform the existing:

```
          day  value_mean  value_max
0  2020-01-01           1         40
1  2020-01-02           5        100
```

To something like:

```
                            value
          day         mean        max
0  2020-01-01           1         40
1  2020-01-02           5        100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem join no `Multiindex` with `MultiIndex columns`, only trick should be use empty strings for second level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x if pd.notna(x) else '')
print (df)
          day value     
               mean  max
0  2020-01-01     1   40
1  2020-01-02     5  100

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(  'day',     ''),
            ('value', 'mean'),
            ('value',  'max')],
           )
```

If want clean, not empty strings values in levels:

```
df = df.set_index('day')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
           value     
            mean  max
day                  
2020-01-01     1   40
2020-01-02     5  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['value', 'day'], ['mean','max','']], codes=[[1,0,0],[2,0,1]])
```

Output:

```
    day         value
                mean    max
0   2020-01-01  1       40
1   2020-01-02  5       100
```